# Adding custom columns to the details view in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arccatalog

When you right click an MXD in ArcCatalog and go to properties you have the option to add a description to your MXD.  The description field can also be set from ArcMap.  What I would like to know is if there is any way to add this description field as a column within ArcCatalog detail view.  There are many ways to customize which columns appear in the detail view using the Customize/ArcCatalog Options/Contents tab.  I've read a few instructions for 9.3 that led me to believe you could do this through the use of XML tags but I haven't been able to achieve anything like this in 10.3.  I understand that MXD's are the only filetype that would contain the property I want in the "description column" and I know the details columns are typically based on properties that would exist in any file type.  Maybe this is a pipe dream, but if anyone has done this please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to show the description for the map document in 10.3 is to use the Catalog window in ArcCatalog while having the Description tab enabled:
By clicking the map document you want to learn more about, the Description tab will be updated based on what parameters you have edited for the map document.

[image]

Another workaround is to use the Title information. Create a new map document and save it in ArcMap. Go to the Document Properties and enter something in the Title window. It does not show up in the Title column though (add Title column from the Metadata columns of the Contents tab of the ArcCatalog Options window).

However, if you select the map document and modify the title under the Description tab (click Edit and then update) and then save, the Title column will show the info entered. This could serve as a description for the map document.